# temp.readline() empty?

Tags: python

I'm able to create and write to a temp file, however when reading the file lines are empty. I confirmed temp file has content. Here is my code. Thanks

```
import tempfile
temp = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile()

with open("~/somefile.txt") as inf:
    for line in inf:
        if line==line.lstrip():
            temp.write(line)

line = str(temp.readline()).strip()
print line #nothing
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You have to re-open (or rewind) the temp file before you can read from it:

```
import tempfile
temp = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile()

with open("~/somefile.txt") as inf:
    for line in inf:
        if line==line.lstrip():
            temp.write(line)

temp.seek(0) # <=============== ADDED

line = str(temp.readline()).strip()
print line
```

Otherwise, the file pointer is positioned at the end of the file when you call `temp.readline()`.

Comment: How come I don't see "seek" in the docs "10.6. tempfile — Generate temporary files and directories" It's working and thank you.

Comment: @fpena06: `NamedTemporaryFile()` returns "a file-like object". The docs for file objects are here: http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#file-objects